# Merge objects with same value from an array into a new object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects

```
let array = [
  {
    "Reg_No": 201500445,
    "Name": "ADITYA KUMAR ",
    "ELECTIVE": "Advanced Web Technologies"
  },
  {
    "Reg_No": 201700150,
    "Name": "N. GAGAN SAI REDDY",
    "ELECTIVE": "Advanced Java"
  },
  {
    "Reg_No": 201700150,
    "Name": "N. GAGAN SAI REDDY",
    "ELECTIVE": "Digital Image Processing"
  },
  {
    "Reg_No": 201700150,
    "Name": "N. GAGAN SAI REDDY",
    "ELECTIVE": "Enterprise Resource Planning"
  },
  {
    "Reg_No": 201700181,
    "Name": "RANJAN SENGUPTA",
    "ELECTIVE": "Advanced Java"
  },
  {
    "Reg_No": 201700181,
    "Name": "RANJAN SENGUPTA",
    "ELECTIVE": "Digital Image Processing"
  },
  {
    "Reg_No": 201700181,
    "Name": "RANJAN SENGUPTA",
    "ELECTIVE": "Internet, Technology and Society"
  },
  {
    "Reg_No": 201700432,
    "Name": "SAMRAT HALDAR",
    "ELECTIVE": "Advanced Java"
  }
]
```

I want the objects with the same Reg_No to be merged into one object while creating a property to hold the values of all the ELECTIVE
i.e I want something like

```
{
  "Reg_No": 201700150,
  "Name": "N. GAGAN SAI REDDY",
  "ELECTIVE": [
    "Advanced Java",
    "Digital Image Processing",
    "Enterprise Resource Planning"
  ]
}
```

for each object with the same Reg_No in the array.
I tried using lodash but I don't know how to merge the Elective into an array.
I've tried

```
var result = _(array)
  .groupBy('id')
  .map(_.spread(_.assign))
  .value();
```

But it results in only one of the ELECTIVE subjects being retained. Is there a way to keep all of the ELECTIVE stored in one array for that object.

Comment: What did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried.

Comment: I searched for how to merge objects with same value in an array and I got const result = _6th_raw_final.filter(v => {
    return v.Reg_No ? !Object.assign(v.Reg_No) : v.Reg_No = v
}, {});. But it returns an empty array

Answer (score -1):

You can use `reduce` -

```js
const array = [{
  Reg_No: 201500445,
  Name: 'ADITYA KUMAR ',
  ELECTIVE: 'Advanced Web Technologies'
}, {
  Reg_No: 201700150,
  Name: 'N. GAGAN SAI REDDY',
  ELECTIVE: 'Advanced Java'
}, {
  Reg_No: 201700150,
  Name: 'N. GAGAN SAI REDDY',
  ELECTIVE: 'Digital Image Processing'
}, {
  Reg_No: 201700150,
  Name: 'N. GAGAN SAI REDDY',
  ELECTIVE: 'Enterprise Resource Planning'
}, {
  Reg_No: 201700181,
  Name: 'RANJAN SENGUPTA',
  ELECTIVE: 'Advanced Java'
}, {
  Reg_No: 201700181,
  Name: 'RANJAN SENGUPTA',
  ELECTIVE: 'Digital Image Processing'
}, {
  Reg_No: 201700181,
  Name: 'RANJAN SENGUPTA',
  ELECTIVE: 'Internet, Technology and Society'
}, {
  Reg_No: 201700432,
  Name: 'SAMRAT HALDAR',
  ELECTIVE: 'Advanced Java'
}];

var reducedSet = [];
array.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  const existing = accumulator.find(a => a.Reg_No === currentValue.Reg_No);
  if (existing) {
    existing.ELECTIVE.push(currentValue.ELECTIVE);
  } else {
    currentValue.ELECTIVE = [currentValue.ELECTIVE]
    accumulator.push(currentValue)
  }
  return accumulator;
}, reducedSet);

console.log(reducedSet);
```

Comment: Thank you for that...even though I have no idea what you did..